# AngularJS v1.2 ngAnimate and ngView

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm wondering why this does not work like excepted. Simply try to fade/in/out the content of the ng-view. Not done much with css3 animations. Maybe there is a mistake in my thoughts.
 Please check out this [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/NLZb3VvE832CMGdFQaRt?p=preview) (Plunker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out.
The directive changed. Check the docs here:

http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/ngAnimate

Here is a forked plunkr that demonstrates:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MJZhZW2gCrTBE5XWWJEj?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

First off, in angular 1.2 the ng-animate directive is deprecated. You can simply put the class you want on there. So we make a class called pageFade that looks like:

```
.pageFade.ng-enter, .pageFade.ng-leave{
 //transition styles
}

.pageFade.ng-enter{
 opacity: 0;
}
.pageFade.ng-enter-active{
 opacity:1;
}

.pageFade.ng-leave{
 opacity:1;
}
.pageFade.ng-leave-active{
 opacity:0;
}
```

Then, in the view:

```
<div ng-view class="pageFade"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To those who may have the same question I created a simple demonstration of how `ngView` can transition with animations. Check out this **[demo project](http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/)**.

In short you basically only need to define animation rules in CSS using `ng-enter`, `ng-enter-active`, `ng-leave`, `ng-leave-active` classes. Also remember to include `ngAnimate` dependency to your module.

Hope it helps someone.